# Troubles with for loop, .append, np.asarray

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop, append

From an excelsheet, I import various columns and I write:

```
import numpy as np
totaloutput = []

inputdata = np.stack(various columns)
for "number of variables in columns" in inputdata:
     calculate several numpy.ndarray-type arrays
     output = np.column_stack(several numpy.ndarray-type arrays)
totaloutput.append(output)
```

When I print `totaloutput`, I get:

```
[array([['0.8', '4.0', '0.5', '5.0', 'X','Y', '16.0',
    '345.0', '285.0', '0.5843940254127079', '0.3583943421752271'],
   ['0.8', '4.0', '0.5', '5.0', 'X','Y', '17.0',
    '345.0', '285.0', '0.36329780170652354', '0.22314099222162737'],
   [etc], 
   [etc]],dtype='<U32'), array([['1.2', '4.0', '0.5', '5.0', 'X', 'Y',
   '16.0',
   '345.0', '15.0', '0.787996644827825', '0.48299132454894594'],
   [etc],
   [etc]],dtype='<U32'),
```

The type of the output according to `type(totaloutput)` is a `list`. However, to be able to export the data, I have to manage to get the data in the following shape:

```
[['0.800000011920929' '3.5' '1.0' '4.0' 'X', 'Y', '15.0'
'345.0' '285.0' '0.6222837267695641' '0.37663730483688007']
['0.800000011920929' '3.5' '1.0' '4.0'  'X', 'Y', '15.0'
'345.0' '285.0' '1.4079677072051757' '0.8500865690052523'][etc][etc]]
```

I thought I solved it by saying:

```
totaloutput = np.asarray(totaloutput)
totaloutput = np.reshape((totaloutput, ((len(inputdata)),11))
```

Whenever I extend the amount of `inputdata` (which is the goal of the script, to automatically calculate for a large amount of data), `np.asarray` does not seem to work anymore. I've found someone having [problems with this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5975) too.

I can confirm this by printing `totaloutput` before `np.asarray(totaloutput)` and afterwards and state that both prints are the same. (the unwished array=...dtype thing) The weird thing is, when after `np.asarray(totaloutput)` I print the `type`, it does says `numpy.ndarray`

With a smaller `inputdata`, after `np.asarray(totaloutput)`, it generates a neat `numpy.ndarray` output.

I've tried lots of other ways to get a right output, I've seen that

```
for i in range(len(inputdata)):
    print(totaloutput.item(i))
```

Is exactly what I need, but whenever I try:

```
for i in range(len(inputdata)):
    finaloutput = (totaloutput.item(i))
```

I get

> totaloutput = (totaloutput.item(i))
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has
>   no attribute 'item'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your problem is you have list of numpy array, you want to stack it into one list?

If it is correct. Have tried `np.vstack()`

[image: Numpy Example]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much